# Rails - Specify a fixed length column in DB migration with PostgresSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

It seems that among column modifiers there's only `:limit`, which specifies the maximum length of this column. However, what if I want to specify the length to be exact? For example a cellphone number must have 11 digits, so I won't want the user to enter an invalid number. Of course I can also carry out the validation in model logic or even front-end, however it seems to be safer to add a constrain at DB level. Is there a way to achieve this in Rails? Or do I have to use Postgre-specific commands. If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails itself only supports a limited set of constraints. You can run arbitrary SQL commands through `execute`, though:

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:addresses) do |t|
      t.string :phone_number, null: false
    end

    execute "ALTER TABLE addresses ADD CONSTRAINT addresses_phone_length CHECK (length(phone_number) = 11)"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mv-core (https://github.com/vprokopchuk256/mv-core) for that. It allows you to define db - level validation in a way that is similar to one in Rails.

For example, your problem might be resolved in two ways with that gem:

1. As predefined validation

```rb
def change
  create_table :addresses do |t|
    t.string :phone_number, length: 11
  end
end
```

2. As custom validation

```rb
def change
  create_table :addresses do |t|
    t.string :phone_number, validates: 'TRIM(LENGTH({phone_number})) = 11'
  end
end
```

3. As predefined validation with custom message:

```rb
def change
  create_table :addresses do |t|
    t.string :phone_number, 
      validates: { length: { is: 11, message: 'should have length == 11' } }
  end
end
```

That database validation can be level up to model as standard ActiveModel validation if you need it:

```rb
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  enforce_migration_validations
end
```

As result you'll have standard ActiveRecord validation behaviour